Is there an effort underway to restore tag highlighting to the new main page?
Is tag highlighting for questions going to restored to the main page?
As I approach 60, scanning small tags to find relevant questions on the new home page is unworkable. It simply produces a headache. So I've resorted to using https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest But I notice the number of questions listed is smaller than the number listed on the new main page.
It would really be helpful to restore tag highlighting of questions to the main page, especially for those older users and those visually challenged. The highlighting of questions for those tags I've set as interested really made the main page usable.
Is there an effort to restore the lost functionality, or is interested tag highlighting of questions lost forever on the main page?
